# Can't move tabs in Chromium -- it always moves to a new window

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, chromium-os

I'm on Arch Linux running Chromium Version 97.0.4692.71. When I click a tab to try to move it left or right, it always moves to a new window. This started happening today after I ran a system upgrade last nite: `yay -Syyu`.

The same tab problem happens in Brave web browser. But not in Firefox.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I hadn't realized it, but I just checked and I can confirm I see the same behavior on my Arch with Chromium 96.0.4664.45 Arch Linux.

Comment: This was fixed in this morning's **Brave** update, but its Chrome version is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I just ran `yay -R brave-bin`, followed by `yay -S brave-bin`, but still encounter the same error in Brave.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I upgraded `brave-bin` with `yay` to version 1.34.80-1. Did you close, then restart Brave?

Comment: Yes. I rebooted my computer too.

Comment: In my case, it worked on one profile, but not on another (I had both open). However, after updating to Chromium 97.0.4692.71 Arch Linux today, it seems to be working on both. Try a `sudo pacman -Sy; sudo pacman -S chromium`, and restart chromium, does it work now?

Comment: Sorry. I just realized that you were already using that exact version. So something is very strange here...

Comment: I'm on Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit). Bug is fixed from that version on at least.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Ubuntu and Chrome/Chromium
It is a Bug:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1279532